# Auto download the file attachment using PHPWord

Tags: php, phpword

I'm trying to use PHPWord to generate word documents. And the document can be generated successfully. But there is a problem where my generated word document will be saved on the server. How can I make it available to download straight away?

Sample:

```
$PHPWord = new PHPWord();
//Searching for values to replace
$document = $PHPWord->loadTemplate('doc/Temp1.docx');
$document->setValue('Name', $Name);
$document->setValue('No', $No);
$document->save('php://output'); //it auto save into my 'doc' directory.
```

How can i link to the header to download it as follows:

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='php://output'"); //not sure how to link this filename to the php://output..
```

Kindly advise.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[`php://output`](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) is a write-only stream, that writes to your screen (like `echo`).

<strike>So, `$document->save('php://output');` will not save the file anywhere on the server, it will just echo it out.</strike>

Seems, `$document->save`, doesn't support stream wrappers, so it literally made a file called `"php://output"`.  Try using another file name (I suggest a temp file, as you just want to echo it out).

```
$temp_file = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'PHPWord');
$document->save($temp_file);
```

In the `header`, the `filename` field is what PHP tells the browser the file is named, it doesn't have to be a name of a file on the server.  It's just the name the browser will save it as.

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='myFile.docx'");
```

So, putting it all together:

```
$PHPWord = new PHPWord();
//Searching for values to replace
$document = $PHPWord->loadTemplate('doc/Temp1.docx');
$document->setValue('Name', $Name);
$document->setValue('No', $No);
// // save as a random file in temp file
$temp_file = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'PHPWord');
$document->save($temp_file);

// Your browser will name the file "myFile.docx"
// regardless of what it's named on the server 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='myFile.docx'");
readfile($temp_file); // or echo file_get_contents($temp_file);
unlink($temp_file);  // remove temp file
```

Comment: Hi it did actually save it into my doc directory. And when I named a filename for the header attachment. It manage to download but the contents are empty inside.

Comment: @JLearner: Ah, ok.  I see what's going on.  `$document->save` doesn't support stream wrappers, so it's making a file literally named `"php://output"`.  Change that to another file name, then use `echo file_get_contents('fileName.docx')` to echo it to the browser.

Comment: echo the file_ge_contents at header part? or?

Comment: @JLearner: `file_get_contents` outputs the file, so it needs to be after the `header` call.

Comment: if i wish to save the file in a specific folder, I can't use tempnam already right? I wish to save it back to the specific folder like doc/1..

Comment: @JLearner: Where do you want to save it?  To the server or to the client?

Comment: to the server. Like now you have it store as a temp file. I would like the temp file be inside one of my server directory like 'doc/test/'

Comment: @JLearner: Then don't use the `tempnam` line.  `$document->save('doc/test/file.docx');`  Then do this later on: `readfile('doc/test/file.docx')`.

Comment: @JLearner: So want to save it to the server *and* download it to the client?

Comment: It doesn't work for the save to 'doc/test/file.docx'. I just want to keep a copy of that file. Save and download to the client at the same time...

Comment: @JLearner: What do you mean "It doesn't work"?  What's happening?

Comment: I put $filename = "doc/test/".$No."/file.docx". Then call out my $document->save('$filename') but it did not save or download any file now

Comment: yes. I'm struggling with this path.. Did I code somewhere wrong? Because the html attachment also doesn't shows out

Comment: @JLearner: Try using an absolute path?  `/var/www/doc/test/123/test.docx`?

Comment: @JLearner: Cool.  Make sure that variable is what you think it is.

Comment: I had to use to $document->saveAs($temp_file); to make it work with docx templates, the save() method produced just an empty document.

Answer (score 11):

```
$objWriter = PHPWord_IOFactory::createWriter($PHPWord, 'Word2007');

$filename = 'MyFile.docx';

$objWriter->save($filename);

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
flush();
readfile($filename);
unlink($filename); // deletes the temporary file
exit;
```

Comment: i tried your code, but it says for each header-line a "header already sent"-warning. After that it prints weird symbols like '���% �t��E�tw�t��(�t��t�Ew' to my network-console in the browser.

Comment: worked perfectly, though I did not use your objWriter - But with templates and `saveAs` it works as intended

Answer (score 6):

This is work for me:

```
$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007', $download = true);

header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='File.docx'");

$objWriter->save("php://output");
```

Comment: This method is way much faster than the *save-and-readfile* method. This is because this solution is not passing through the storage I/O.

Answer (score 3):

now whit Ver 0.13.0
https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord

```
<?
require_once "../include/PHPWord-develop/bootstrap.php";

$templateProcessor = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor('template.docx');

$templateProcessor->setValue('var01', 'Sun');
$templateProcessor->setValue('var02', 'Mercury');

//#####################################################
// Save File
//#####################################################
//#####################################################
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='output01.docx'");
  $templateProcessor->saveAs('php://output');
//#####################################################
//#####################################################
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution for Laravel based on @user3214824 answer.

```
// ...    
$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($PHPWord, 'Word2007');
$doc_name = 'fileName.docx';
$objWriter->save($doc_name); // saving in the public path just for testing

return response()->download(public_path($doc_name))->deleteFileAfterSend(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry this came in later. I stumbled on this while trying to solve the same problem. I was able to get it working on Laravel 5 using below:

```
    $file_dir = $template_upload_dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'filename.docx';
    $tags = array();
    if (file_exists($file_dir)) {
        $templateProcessor = new TemplateProcessor($file_dir);
        $tags = $templateProcessor->getVariables();
        $replace = array(''); 

        $templateProcessor->setValue($tags, $replace);
        $save_file_name = $fullname.'-'.$inv_code.'-'.date('YmdHis').'.docx';
        $templateProcessor->saveAs($save_file_name);

        return response()->download($save_file_name)->deleteFileAfterSend(true);
    }
```

Hope it helps someone!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
// Save File
$objWriter = PHPWord_IOFactory::createWriter($PHPWord, 'Word2007');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='myFile.docx'");
$objWriter->save("php://output");
```

Comment: Hello.  Congratulations on your first post.  Could you give some additional text clarifying what your answer is doing?

Comment: download the file attachment as a docx :)

Answer (score 0):

I am using laravel `10.x` and PHPWord `1.1`. After trying mutiple solutions I have use laravel `StreamedResponse` class based on the [medium article](https://medium.com/@barryvdh/streaming-large-csv-files-with-laravel-chunked-queries-4158e484a5a2) by [@barryvdh](https://medium.com/@barryvdh) to stream large CSV I have modified the code to work with [PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord)

```
        $phpWordInstance = new PhpWord();
        //all your other code here
        $fileName = 'test.docx';

        $streamedResponse = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\StreamedResponse(callback : function () use ($phpWordInstance,$fileName) {
            $xmlWriter = IOFactory::createWriter($phpWordInstance, 'Word2007');
            $xmlWriter->save('php://output');
        },
            status: 200,
            headers: [
                'Content-Type' => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
                'Content-Disposition' => sprintf('attachment; filename="%s"',$fileName),
            ]);

        return $streamedResponse;
```

And for the mimetype pls refeer to [What is a correct MIME type for .docx, .pptx, etc.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212861/what-is-a-correct-mime-type-for-docx-pptx-etc)