# Get a corrupted file on download of a DOCX File using PHPWord

Tags: php, phpword

I am trying to use "PHPWord" to download a docx file.

If I try saving the file onto the server it works fine. But if add the headers to download it then the file gets displayed in a corrupted form.

Note: I am opening it using openOffice.

Here is my Code:

```
 $document->save($doc);
 header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
 header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=CV.docx");
 header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
 header('Expires: 0');
 header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
 header('Pragma: public');
 header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($doc));
 readfile($doc);
```

Can anyone please tell me what the issue could be?

Comment: If you can download a file, then it's file generation issue, not a download issue, right?

Comment: How corrupt is it? Is the document messed up, some content missing, or complete garbage?

Comment: The file gets downloaded. But the content is complete garbage.

Comment: But if I try saving the file on the server. It displays everything correctly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11476187/1848929

Comment: I tried that. But it still doesn't work.

Comment: Open the file in a text editor and look for leading/trailing whitespace characters or BOM headers, any html markup, or any plaintext messages in the file.... if you find those, act on any error messages you see, or locate the echo/print in your own script, or anything in your script that is outside of the php (`<?php` and `?>`) tags, such as newlines

Comment: Thank you very much. I had echo statements before the header. So it used to give errors.

Comment: @NehaDangui since that was the problem, you should accept my answer :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me take a guess:

Your program outputs some text *before* you sent `header`s (if *you* dont manually `echo` something it may be a php warning, that counts as output too). So in the actual output of your file, if you open it with a simple text editor as `txt` (just rename the extension to `.txt` and open it with notepad) the first lines will be something like:

`Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /some/file.php:12) in /some/file.php on line 23`

...and then the rest of your `doc` file. Of course that is corrupted.

If thats the case you should not output *anything* before the `header`s

Comment: Came here because of the same issue and this has given me a proper idea what was wrong. My code outputted text **after** the generated file. Note that I'm using `$xmlWriter->save("php://output");` method to download file, I'm not saving it to server.