# In PHPWord how can I bypass the Popup screen

Tags: php, phpword

I have the popup with a button to select a DOCX. This is the only selection. How can I emulate pressing this button, so the Popup is one less task to perform? The User does not need to see this screen.

Comment: Please share your current code to display what you have done and to get a better picture of your actual problem; with this description it doesn't sound like something that would be actually related to phpword (question about popups with user interaction that is)...

Comment: Here is some source code displaying the result of the PHPWord screen that popup:

    echo "&nbsp;" .date('H:i:s'),' Saving the result document to 
    downloads\nameBadge.docx', EOL;
$templateProcessor->saveAs('results/nameBadge.docx');
    echo getEndingNotes(array('Word2007' => 'docx'));
    if (!CLI) {
    include_once 'Sample_Footer.php';
}
    echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Click on <b>docx</b> to open the Word document. Word or open office must be installed";

As you can see I am instructing the user to click on the button to run Word.

Comment: `echo "&nbsp;" .date('H:i:s'),' Saving the result document to downloads\nameBadge.docx', EOL;'
' $templateProcessor->saveAs('results/nameBadge.docx');
 echo getEndingNotes(array('Word2007' => 'docx'));'
'if (!CLI) { include_once 'Sample_Footer.php'; } 
    echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Click on <b>docx</b> to open the Word document. Word or open office must be installed"`

Comment: It would be better for readability & re-usability of the question if you could update that code to your original question directly :) You could take a look how the word document can be returned automatically to the user after generation from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11476058/auto-download-the-file-attachment-using-phpword for example (if I understood what you are after correctly) - you can ofc also just implement some client side code to do the clicking for the user but I assume the first option of serving the file directly is more what you are after (?)

Comment: Client side code would work for me. Just did not know how to go about it. I assume I would need to modify the PHPWord files somewhere which is not a preferred option.

Comment: server side option = the link above, client side option = javascript.